# What is the French equivalent of the English linguistic term "reflex" (the descendant sound of a sound in a proto-language)?

Tags: english, terminology, french, translation

I looked it up in different dictionaries but could not find anything. Thank you in advance.

Comment: As a question on linguistic terminology, I see no reason to close it.

Comment: I have no proof, but I always figured it was reflecting "reflection". No idea why it's "reflex" instead, probably in allusion to "(in)flexion".

Answer (score 1):

Bonne question ! Personnally, I write "reflet" for the noun and "être reflété" (to be reflected) for the verb. This may be an anglicism, but I can't think of something else.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the word "réflexe", but the word "dérivé" is much more used.

Answer (score 0):

[Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/reflex) says it's [*continuateur*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/continuateur#French), but I couldn't really confirm this is actually a technical term after a cursory search. The [French Wiktioanry](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/reflex) defines the linguistic sense of English *reflex* as "Issue, continuateur ou aboutissement d’un étymon ou d’un phonème étymologique." There might not be an established counterpart in French.

Comment: it seems that "continuateur" is only used by one person: Marta Andronache.